# ¿Como usar ref en una expresión lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda

he tratado de usar una expresión lambda que con parámetro de referencia de una posición de una matriz pero me salen errores, el error es en la variable item.

```
delegate void accion(ref int x);

static void Main(string [] Args) 
    {
        int[][] m = new int[3][];
        m[0] = new int[2];
        m[1] = new int[5];
        m[2] = new int[10];
        accion ac = new accion(Ac);
        recorrer(m,item => item = new Random().Next(0,1000) );
        recorrer(m,item => Console.WriteLine(item));
    }

   public static void recorrer(int [][] m, accion ac)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].Length; j++)
            {
                ac(ref m[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

el error concretamente dice que el parámetro debe de estar declarado con la palabra ref, se la puse y me salio otro error de que la variable debe de ser asignable, Después mejor los hice en métodos para el delegado y ahí si funciona

```
public static void Ac(ref int item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

public static void Ac(ref int item)
{
    item = new Random().Next(0,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe declarar explícitamente el tipo de la variable:

```
recorrer(m, (ref int item) => item = new Random().Next(0,1000) );
```

Comment: muchas gracias :)